# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la base de datos de mysql a través de un contenedor creado con Docker?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, linux, docker, docker-compose

Quisiera saber la forma de acceder al servidor de mysql que se encuentra en un contenedor Docker, debido a que estoy creando una aplicación con nodejs cuyo gestor de base de datos es mysql. Estoy iniciando con Docker, y debido a que la aplicación no me reconoce la tabla de la base de datos porque no existe, no estoy seguro si los archivos **docker-compose.yml** y **Dockerfile** se encuentran creados correctamente.
La aplicación parece ser desplegada correctamente en el puerto asignado, pero no la he podido ejecutar con la base de datos.

Este es el archivo Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app-example3

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Y este el archivo docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

  services:
    db:
      image: mysql:latest
      container_name: composer_mysql
      ports: 
        - "3306:3306"
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
          MYSQL_DATABASE: users
      volumes:
        - "/home/ubuntupc/Documentos/DockerVolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      restart: always
    nodejs:
      build: .
      image: node_app
      container_name: composer_nodejs
      command: npm start
      volumes:
        - ".:/app-example3"
      ports:
        - "3997:3000"
      depends_on:
        - db
      links:
        - db
      environment:
        DB_HOST: db:3306
        DB_USER: root
        DB_PASS: admin
        DB_PORT: "3306"
        WAIT_HOSTS_TIMEOUT: 100
```

Agradezco mucho si alguien me puede colaborar. Quedo pendiente a posibles soluciones.

Comment: De primera mano lo que puedo notar en la seccion enviroment: no estas definiendo el usuario de mysql, prueba con MYSQL_USER: 'root'

Comment: Ya he puesto el valor pero sigue igual, no se está conectando la base de datos con la aplicación

Comment: Probaste conectarte al contenedor Mysql desde Workbench por ejemplo, no desde la aplicacion? Para garantizar que tienes funcionando bien el servidor mysql?. Mira este [Link](https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1432-docker/3268-como-crear-un-contenedor-con-docker-mysql-y-persistir-la-informacion/)

Comment: Sí, ya lo hice y al parecer el archivo sí está creando correctamente la base de datos y las tablas. Mi problema reside en que la aplicación por alguna razón no se está conectando con ese servidor para el almacenamiento de la información