# Problemas al conectar una aplicación de nodejs con mysql a través de contenedores Docker

Tags: nodejs, linux, express, docker, docker-compose

Soy nuevo en Docker, y he tenido un problema que no sé cómo puedo solucionar.
Necesito crear un contenedor para una aplicación de nodejs y otro para el servidor de base de datos mysql. Investigando he construido el Dockerfile para node, cuya imagen la llamé node_v3. Este es el archivo:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app-exmple

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

De igual manera he creado el archivo **docker-compose.yml** que luce así:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db_composer
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
        MYSQL_DATABASE: users
    volumes:
      - "/home/ubuntupc/Documentos/DockerVolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./src/sql/database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql"
  nodejs:
    image: node_v3
    container_name: app_composer
    ports:
      - "3997:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - net
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db:3306
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: admin
      DB_PORT: "3306"
networks:
  net:
```

Luego ejecuto el archivo, y los contenedores comienzan a ejecutarse, logro acceder satisfactoriamente a la aplicación, pero al agregar información que debe almacenarse en la base de datos, parece que dicha información no se está guardando, porque reviso la base de datos y las tablas aparecen vacías. Accedo a los datos así:

```
sudo docker exec -it db_composer mysql -p
```

La base de datos se crea y también las tablas. Pero parece no estar conectada a la aplicación. La conexión desde la aplicación la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = () => {
  return mysql.createConnection({
    //host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    host: 'db',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'users'
  });
}
```

Agradezco mucho si alguien me puede colaborar con la solución al problema que presento.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo acceder a la base de datos de mysql a través de un contenedor creado con Docker?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345930/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-acceder-a-la-base-de-datos-de-mysql-a-trav%c3%a9s-de-un-contenedor-creado)

Answer (score 1):

Según veo en el código, creo que el error lo tienes en como estas obteniendo las variables de entorno del contenedor `app_composer`, la estar recogiendo como un string cuando dentro del contenedor se recoge con `process.env`.

Para el caso de variables de entorno, lo que yo haría es utilizar un archivo `.env` donde tuviera las variables declaradas y inyectarla en el contenedor que las necesites, de esa forma esta todo encapsulado en un mismo archivo y si tienes que cambiarlas es mas fácil, ya que el archivo `docker-compose.yml` puede ser bastante extenso en algunos casos.

Archivo `.env`:

```
  MYSQL_HOST=db_composer    # Nombre del contenedor que es el que publica Docker
  MYSQL_USER=root
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
  MYSQL_DATABASE=users
  MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

Archivo `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db_composer
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - net
    env_file:
      -.env    # Ruta del archivo
    volumes:
      - "/home/ubuntupc/Documentos/DockerVolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./src/sql/database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database.sql"
  nodejs:
    image: node_v3
    container_name: app_composer
    ports:
      - "3997:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - net
    links:
      - db
    env_file:
      -.env    # Ruta del archivo
networks:
  net:
```

Para realizar la conexión seria así:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

// Aqui obtienes las variables de entorno que inyectas en el contenedor
const { MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE } = process.env      

module.exports = () => {
  return mysql.createConnection({
    host: MYSQL_HOST,
    user: MYSQL_USER,
    password: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
    database: MYSQL_DATABASE
  });
}
```

En el caso de `mysql` el puerto por defecto es 3306, por lo que no es necesario indicarlo.

Espero que con esta solución este resuleto tu problema, sino no dudes en consultar.

Un saludo